# Where is IQueryable in the .NET Compact Framework?

Tags: c#, linq, compact-framework

I have started to develop a repository using LINQ to SQL against SQL CE in a Windows project.  This works fine.  However, when I went to port the code over to .NET CF for a Windows Mobile application, the IQueryable does not appear to exist.

What is the best way to make this work across Mobile and Desktop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It simply isn't there - most notably, because neither is `Expression` (although you can [reintroduce pieces of that](http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2009/04/re-implementing-expression-for-compact.html) if you need).

Simply, you'll have to limit yourself to "regular" code for data-access (LINQ-to-SQL etc) / services (ADO.NET Data Services etc). Of course, when you *have* data from whatever source, you can still use `IEnumerable<T>`, so there are plenty of *local* options for data query.

Comment: Any suggestions for ORM then?  Or back to writing my own data access layer?

Answer (score 0):

It's in [`System.Linq`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.aspx)

**Edit:**

Withdrawn - I didn't see he was looking at *Compact* framework.  The documentation doesn't say anything specific about it for compact framework (meaning it's probably not included, but that's not conclusive).  I'll leave this up for now to help others avoid my mistake.